# JOOQ - Update newly added columns

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, jooq

I am using JOOQ and a Postgresql Database and I'm trying to add new columns to a table and then update those columns with values. Those values correspond to sentiment of a tweet.

My attempt so far (the one without compilation errors :) is:

```
final String SENTIMENT_NEGATIVE = "sentiment_negative";
final String SENTIMENT_NEUTRAL  = "sentiment_neutral";
final String SENTIMENT_POSITIVE = "sentiment_positive";
final String SENTIMENT_COMPOUND = "sentiment_compound";

context.alterTable(Tweets.TWEETS).addColumnIfNotExists(SENTIMENT_NEGATIVE, DOUBLE).execute();
context.alterTable(Tweets.TWEETS).addColumnIfNotExists(SENTIMENT_NEUTRAL , DOUBLE).execute();
context.alterTable(Tweets.TWEETS).addColumnIfNotExists(SENTIMENT_POSITIVE, DOUBLE).execute();
context.alterTable(Tweets.TWEETS).addColumnIfNotExists(SENTIMENT_COMPOUND, DOUBLE).execute();

// example usage
for (Record record: tweetsResult) {
    String tweet = record.get(Tweets.TWEETS.CONTENT);
    SentimentAnalyzer sentimentAnalyzer = new SentimentAnalyzer(tweet);
    sentimentAnalyzer.analyze();
    log.debug(sentimentAnalyzer.getPolarity() + " | " + tweet);

    context.update(Tweets.TWEETS)
        .set(
            row(SENTIMENT_NEGATIVE,
               SENTIMENT_NEUTRAL,
               SENTIMENT_POSITIVE,
               SENTIMENT_COMPOUND),
            row(getPolarity(sentimentAnalyzer, SENTIMENT_NEGATIVE),
                getPolarity(sentimentAnalyzer, SENTIMENT_NEUTRAL),
                getPolarity(sentimentAnalyzer, SENTIMENT_POSITIVE),
                getPolarity(sentimentAnalyzer, SENTIMENT_COMPOUND))
            )
        .where(Tweets.TWEETS.ID.eq(record.get(Tweets.TWEETS.ID)))
        .execute();
}
```

but I get an error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [update "public"."tweets" set (?, ?, ?, ?) = row (?, ?, ?, ?) where "public"."tweets"."id" = ?]; ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"

I know that I can regenerate my source code according to the changes in db schema, but I wonder if it is possible to do it using my approach.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't re-generate the code after your `ALTER TABLE` execution?

Comment: It's a school assignment and I need it to consistently run on other devices, so it would be ideal to reconstruct from another computer without having to switch between versions, configurations and different runs.

Comment: But your development version is already aware of the new columns, so why not have at least your development version work on generated code? You can still apply a migration if needed...

Comment: I don't know if I understand you correctly - U need to work with the columns that I just created (and are not yet generated). Edit: If regeneration is the only way, I can work with that, I just need to know if there is a better way :)

Comment: It *is* the better way, trust me. I provided an answer with some links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you'll implement a cleaner separation of your querying logic and your migration logic. Database change management tools like [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) or [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/) will help you maintain your schema, and apply increments whenever your application starts.

Once you use database change management software, you can use it as well during your development, e.g. by applying your increments all the time to your development database within testcontainers, from which you then re-generate your code, see

- [A jOOQ / testcontainers / Flyway example](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/tree/main/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-testcontainers-flyway-example)
- [The manual's jOOQ / Flyway tutorial](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/tutorials/jooq-with-flyway/)

That way, your generated code is always up to date, and you don't have to resort to using temporary type-unsafe `String` representations of your latest columns.

Comment: I now understand the logic behind code generation and working with up-to-date classes much better. Thank you for clarification